# SQL: Query for a group that contains an exact set of users

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a simple many-to-many join table of users and groups such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`  (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_group` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `group_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Michael'),
  ('2', 'Sarah'),
  ('3', 'Steven'),
  ('4', 'Jane');

INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'M Names'),
  ('2', 'S Names'),
  ('3', 'J Names'),
  ('4', 'Men'),
  ('5', 'Women');

INSERT INTO `user_group` (`user_id`, `group_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '4'),
  ('2', '2'),
  ('2', '5'),
  ('3', '2'),
  ('3', '4'),
  ('4', '3'),
  ('4', '5');
```

I am trying to figure out how to see if a given set of users makes up an existing group.

For example, if I query for Michael, it returns the group `M Names` because that group consists entirely of Michael.

If I query for (Sarah, Steven), it returns the group 'S Names'.

If I query for (Sarah, Michael), no group is returned.

It is easy to query for the groups that a given set of users are in:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_group`
WHERE `user_id` in ('2', '3');
```

But I am at a loss on how to limit that to only the groups that all of the given users are a member of.

Comment: I assume that searching for "Michael AND Steven" would be a successful search, as it would return "Men"

Comment: when you say "make up an existing group", do you mean: "are contained in an existing group" (subset), or do yo really want an exact match?

Comment: What you get with (Michael, Sarah, Steven)? M Names and S Names?

Comment: @Jakumi I am looking for an exact match, not any subset.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In that instance, no group would be returned because those three do not make up an exact group.

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: We are using MySQL

Answer (score 3):

(updated, add something to make this not just a subset but an exact match)

I assume you want the groups where all the users are members of together. or where the users are a subset. the following query will do the job (unless I made a mistake)

```
SELECT g.Name
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN user_group ug on (ug.group_id=g.id)
WHERE ug.user_id IN (1,4)
GROUP BY g.id
HAVING COUNT(ug.user_id) = 2
```

explanation: first, you essentially (probably) want to filter `user_group` by `user_id` to find groups containing ANY of the users' ids (`WHERE`-clause), then you want to select the groups, that have ALL the users' ids (`GROUP` and `HAVING`-clause).

However, this query has two varying parts: the user ids in the where clause (`1,4` in this case) and the count of those user_ids in the having clause (`2` in this case).

**update**

Now, since your post suggests you want an exact match, you can **add** the following to the `HAVING`-clause

```
   AND COUNT(ug.user_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_group ug2 WHERE ug2.group_id=g.id)
```

which ensures the counts of users of that group is the same as the query user count.

Comment: The better solution and the first.  I'm surprised I'm the first upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query (works on MySql 8):

```
WITH usr AS (
 SELECT 'Sarah' usr_name
 UNION
 SELECT 'Steven'
),
usr_id AS (
  SELECT * FROM usr 
  LEFT JOIN users u  ON u.name = usr.usr_name
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT group_id
  FROM user_group ug
  LEFT JOIN usr_id u ON ug.user_id = u.id
  GROUP BY group_id
  HAVING count(*) = count(id)
     AND count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM usr)
) qq
JOIN `groups` g ON g.id = qq.group_id
```

Working demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7621f99e0b2d0bf1ec6fbfdc55424c48

> ```
> WITH usr AS (
>  SELECT 'Sarah' usr_name
>  UNION
>  SELECT 'Steven'
> ),
> usr_id AS (
>   SELECT * FROM usr 
>   LEFT JOIN users u  ON u.name = usr.usr_name
> )
> SELECT * FROM (
>   SELECT group_id
>   FROM user_group ug
>   LEFT JOIN usr_id u ON ug.user_id = u.id
>   GROUP BY group_id
>   HAVING count(*) = count(id)
>      AND count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM usr)
> ) qq
> JOIN `groups` g ON g.id = qq.group_id
> ```
>
> ```
> group_id | id | name   
> -------: | -: | :------
>        2 |  2 | S Names
> ```

> ```
> WITH usr AS (
>  SELECT 'Michael' usr_name
> ),
> usr_id AS (
>   SELECT * FROM usr 
>   LEFT JOIN users u  ON u.name = usr.usr_name
> )
> SELECT * FROM (
>   SELECT group_id
>   FROM user_group ug
>   LEFT JOIN usr_id u ON ug.user_id = u.id
>   GROUP BY group_id
>   HAVING count(*) = count(id)
>      AND count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM usr)
> ) qq
> JOIN `groups` g ON g.id = qq.group_id
> ```
>
> ```
> group_id | id | name   
> -------: | -: | :------
>        1 |  1 | M Names
> ```

> ```
> WITH usr AS (
>  SELECT 'Michael' usr_name
>  UNION
>  SELECT 'Sarah'
> ),
> usr_id AS (
>   SELECT * FROM usr 
>   LEFT JOIN users u  ON u.name = usr.usr_name
> )
> SELECT * FROM (
>   SELECT group_id
>   FROM user_group ug
>   LEFT JOIN usr_id u ON ug.user_id = u.id
>   GROUP BY group_id
>   HAVING count(*) = count(id)
>      AND count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM usr)
> ) qq
> JOIN `groups` g ON g.id = qq.group_id
> ```
>
> ```
> group_id | id | name
> -------: | -: | :---
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7621f99e0b2d0bf1ec6fbfdc55424c48)*

Comment: That's a lot of query though.