# Count a select distinct with conditions in it

Tags: sql, oracle

Today I have to write a query for a flight database for school. But right now I'm stuck as I don't know how to continue with it. I need to select the Airlines which have done 1000 or more flights. Because of how we have structured the database, I would have to do it in this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.nombre, 
                a.codigo, 
                count 
                      ( 
                      select distinct o.salida_prevista, 
                                      o.fecha, 
                                      o.identificador 
                      FROM            operacion o 
                      WHERE           EXISTS 
                                      ( 
                                        SELECT DISTINCT v.identificador, 
                                                        v.codigo_aerolinea 
                                        FROM            vuelo v 
                                        WHERE           v.identificador = o.identificador
                                        AND             v.codigo_aerolinea = a.codigo)) AS numflights
FROM            aerolinea a 
WHERE           numflights > 1000;
```

But I can't get the COUNT to work, it'll just throw a syntax error at me. How can I make that COUNT work?
Thank you in advance! :)
EDIT: Creation tables

```
CREATE TABLE Aerolinea (
codigo_aerolinea                VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT PK_Aerolinea         PRIMARY KEY,
nombre                          VARCHAR(75) CONSTRAINT NN_nombre_aerolinea  NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Vuelo (
identificador                   NUMBER      CONSTRAINT PK_Vuelo             PRIMARY KEY,
IATA_origen                     VARCHAR(6),
IATA_destino                    VARCHAR(6),
codigo_aerolinea                VARCHAR(10),
codigo                          VARCHAR(6)  CONSTRAINT NN_codigo_vuelo      NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_IATA_origen                   FOREIGN KEY (IATA_origen)       REFERENCES Aeropuerto(IATA)
                                                                            ON DELETE CASCADE, 
CONSTRAINT FK_IATA_destino                  FOREIGN KEY (IATA_destino)      REFERENCES Aeropuerto(IATA)
                                                                            ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_codigo_aerolinea              FOREIGN KEY (codigo_aerolinea)  REFERENCES Aerolinea(codigo)
                                                                            ON DELETE CASCADE);
CREATE TABLE Operacion(
identificador                   NUMBER,
fecha                           DATE        CONSTRAINT NN_fecha             NOT NULL,
salida_prevista                 NUMBER,
salida_real                     NUMBER,
llegada_prevista                NUMBER      CONSTRAINT NN_llegada_prevista  NOT NULL,
llegada_real                    NUMBER,
numero_cola                     VARCHAR(6),
CONSTRAINT PK_Operacion         PRIMARY KEY (salida_prevista, fecha, identificador),
CONSTRAINT FK_op_vuelo          FOREIGN KEY (identificador)                  REFERENCES Vuelo(identificador)
                                                                            ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_op_numero_cola    FOREIGN KEY(numero_cola)                    REFERENCES Nave(numero_cola)
                                                                            ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's telling me that there's an invalid number of arguments. Sorry if the question is not precise enough. I wanted to upload the table creation file, but it's large and I don't know how.

Comment: the problem is you can't do a `COUNT( SELECT *) ` If you provide some sample data we can help you write the query. Check this question as example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415365/sql-query-for-a-group-that-contains-an-exact-set-of-users

Comment: And how could I have the same functionality without doing that? Thank you for your quick answer

Comment: Is hard to said because I dont understand the relationship between the tables, so I would need to guess. The problem is that would require lot of time and if I guess wrong will be a waste. That is why you need to provide something with more details some sample data and expected output.

Comment: There you have the table creation statements @JuanCarlosOropeza, sorry for the incovenience and I hope I'm not being a burden

Comment: No hay problema amigo. What is the rol of operation there?

Comment: Vuelo is a route ran by a certain airline, and operation is a flight perse. So for example a flight from san francisco to chicago, on the 21st of april at 10 am

Comment: So one Vuelo can have multiple operations on different day/times? and you want Aerolineas with 1000 Vuelos or with 1000 operations?

Comment: Yes, that's it, one Vuelo can have multiple operations, and I want Aerolineas that have 1000 or more operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the rol of operations.

But looks like just need a join

```
 SELECT a.nombre, 
        a.codigo
 FROM aerolinea a
 JOIN vuelo v
   ON a.codigo = v.codigo_aerolinea
 JOIN operations o
   ON o.identificador = v.identificador
 GROUP BY a.nombre, a.codigo
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1000
```

Comment: I add the opertions table. Not sure where/if you need `distrinct`

Comment: Sorry, where should I do the SELECT * order by a.nombre?

Comment: Check again the answer

Comment: It tells me ERROR at line 1: not a single-group group function. Sorry to bother you

Comment: Sorry forgot the group by

Comment: Jesus, now it tells me: not a GROUP BY expression. I'm like, I don't want to bother this guy anymore, but I just don't manage to get it to work. Sorry man

Comment: Sorry I dont see any error. Try creating a sample here http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler so I can have something to work with

Comment: What do you want me to put there? I put the creation tables which were working, and it's throwing me an error

Comment: Okay, sorry, now the query worked, but it didn't show any airlines

Comment: I told you. You need to add sample data. otherwise I will be guessing :(

Comment: Nevermind, the no rows selected was my fault. It's working. Going to mark it as an answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: good. I finally make a working db here.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e135/4 Your field doesnt match your query that took me sometime to fix